# Dividing data into tertiles pandas

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I need help with an statistical pandas issue.

So I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
   user_id          user_total_exercises
   8                    1.0
   32794352             5.0
   28109145             17.0
   26424341             68.0
   32769624             85.0
   26870381             698.0
```

In which the `user_total_exercises` column corresponds to the total number of exercises that the user has completed in a year (i.e 2018).

I also have the total number of exercises accomplished by all users during that same year, called `year_total_exercises = 874`.

Given this data, I would like to divide it into tertiles, in order to obtain the value of user_total_exercises for the user in tertile 1, in tertile 2 and in tertile 3.

The problem is I don't really have a good statistical knowledge to make the tertiles, so any help on this issue would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

UPDATE:

so I used the following:

```
categories = pd.qcut(df['user_total_exercises'], 3, labels=false)
```

And the result I get is this one:

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
```

I don't understand this result. If any one could help I would really appreciate it.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Check out the documentation of [pandas.DataFrame.quantile()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

Comment: Do you mean `pd.qcut(df['user_total_exercises'], 3, labels=False)`?

Comment: I just checked out the documentation of quantile, but don't quite understand how I could use it in this example

Comment: pd.qcut(df['user_total_exercises'], 3, labels=False) returned this: 0   0   1   1   2   2, but I don't know how to interpret this result.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do a similar thing, so I've used your data for the example below. This was adapted from a much more complete quartiles example here [How to split data groups into quartiles by group's size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371504/how-to-split-data-groups-into-quartiles-by-groups-size)

```py
# Create example dataframe (I've reordered the data to make clear it's splitting on value and not position)
data = [[8, 1.0], [26424341, 68.0], [32794352, 5.0], [26870381, 698.0], [28109145, 17.0], [32769624, 85.0]]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['user_id', 'user_total_exercises'])
# Get tertile positions
tertiles = df['user_total_exercises'].quantile([1/3,2/3]).tolist()
# Add a lower and upper range for the bins in pd.cut
tertiles = [0] + tertiles + [float('inf')]
# Add new tertile column to the data frame based on the tertile cut
df['tertile'] = pandas.cut(df['user_total_exercises'], bins=tertiles, labels=['1st', '2nd', '3rd'])
df
```