# How to split data groups into quartiles by group's size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have [a dataset for credit card transaction](https://data.world/oklahoma/purchase-card-fiscal-year).

I split this dataset by group using below code

```py
raw_data = pd.read_csv(dataset_path)  # Load dataset

# or read the dataset directly from data.world with the following
raw_data = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/xapduodvxrzul6tjrupmlqiot4bpex')

groups = raw_data.groupby(list(categories))  # Categories = ('Cardholder Last Name', 'Cardholder First Initial')
```

Then I get size of each group using below code

```py
size_of_groups = groups.size()
```

Here is the graph for you to see the distribution

[image: Distribution]

What I want is divide this groups into quartiles(25%, 50%, 75%, 100%) and save them into csv's.

Example path

```
Groups
|
|--1st_quartile  # Size of group in this directory is in 1st quartile
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
|--2nd_quartile  # Size of group in this directory is in 2nd quartile
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
|--3rd_quartile  # Size of group in this directory is in 3rd quartile
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
|--4th_quartile
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial) # Size of group in this directory is in 4th quartile
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
   |--(Some Cardholder Last Name, Some Cardholder First Initial).csv
```

### Sample data without link

```py
,Year-Month,Agency Number,Agency Name,Cardholder Last Name,Cardholder First Initial,Description,Amount,Vendor,Transaction Date,Posted Date,Merchant Category Code (MCC)
0,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mason,C,GENERAL PURCHASE,890.0,NACAS,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,CHARITABLE AND SOCIAL SERVICE ORGANIZATIONS
1,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mason,C,ROOM CHARGES,368.96,SHERATON HOTEL,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,SHERATON
2,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Massey,J,GENERAL PURCHASE,165.82,SEARS.COM 9300,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,DIRCT MARKETING/DIRCT MARKETERS--NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
3,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Massey,T,GENERAL PURCHASE,96.39,WAL-MART #0137,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"GROCERY STORES,AND SUPERMARKETS"
4,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mauro-Herrera,M,HAMMERMILL COPY PLUS COPY EA,125.96,STAPLES DIRECT,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"STATIONERY, OFFICE SUPPLIES, PRINTING AND WRITING PAPER"
5,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mauro-Herrera,M,GENERAL PURCHASE,394.28,KYOCERA DOCUMENT SOLUTION,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"OFFICE, PHOTOGRAPHIC, PHOTOCOPY, AND MICROFILM EQUIPMENT"
6,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mays,B,GENERAL PURCHASE,19.87,WAL-MART #0137,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"GROCERY STORES,AND SUPERMARKETS"
7,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mays,B,GENERAL PURCHASE,10.1,DAYLIGHT DONUTS,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,FAST FOOD RESTAURANTS
8,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,McCarthy,D,GENERAL PURCHASE,142.6,UFIRST  LAUNDRY SVCS,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"MENS, WOMENS AND CHILDRENS UNIFORMS AND COMMERCIAL CLOTHING"
9,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,McClurg,L,AT&T SERVICE PAYMENT ITM,29.99,AT&T DATA,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,TELECOMMUNICATION SERVICES
10,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,McGowin,R,GENERAL PURCHASE,278.23,RANDY'S FOODS,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,FREEZER AND LOCKER MEAT PROVISIONERS
11,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,McKee,P,GENERAL PURCHASE,127.8,DEARINGER PRINTING & TROP,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,MISCELLANEOUS AND SPECIALTY RETAIL STORES
12,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,McLemore,A,GENERAL PURCHASE,572.27,GIDDINGS MACHINE CO.,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"COMMERCIAL EQUIPMENT, NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED"
13,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,McMurry,S,50-LB PLAY SAND BAG|20 QT POTTING SOIL TIMBERL EA,12.9,LOWES #00241,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,HOME SUPPLY WAREHOUSE STORES
14,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Meints,K,GENERAL PURCHASE,445.0,OK DEPT OF VO-TECH ED,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,GOVERNMENT SERVICES--NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
15,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mohiuddin,A,GENERAL PURCHASE,452.91,TFS THERMOASHEVILLE,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
16,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mohiuddin,I,GENERAL PURCHASE,2425.0,WESTERN EQUIPMENT ALVA,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
17,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mohiuddin,I,GENERAL PURCHASE,2425.0,WESTERN EQUIPMENT ALVA,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
18,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Mollenhauer,R,GENERAL PURCHASE,7.63,HOBBY-LOBBY #0005,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"HOBBY,TOY,AND GAME STORES"
19,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,MONTGOMERY,R,GENERAL PURCHASE,18.97,WAL-MART #0121,07/30/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"GROCERY STORES,AND SUPERMARKETS"
20,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Morales,D,ROOM CHARGES,729.8,WESTIN DENVER DOWNTOWN,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,WESTIN HOTELS
21,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Morales,D,ROOM CHARGES,729.8,WESTIN DENVER DOWNTOWN,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,WESTIN HOTELS
22,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Fokar,M,GENERAL PURCHASE,368.0,BIO RAD,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
23,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Forquer,G,GENERAL PURCHASE,9.16,LOCKE SUPPLY - STILLWATER,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
24,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Forquer,G,GENERAL PURCHASE,1.68,NAPA AUTO PARTS,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,AUTOMOTIVE PARTS AND ACCESSORIES STORES
25,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Foye,S,GENERAL PURCHASE,-30.0,"AFFYMETRIX, INC",07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
26,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Foye,S,GENERAL PURCHASE,178.0,"AFFYMETRIX, INC",07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
27,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Fry,A,GENERAL PURCHASE,27.44,EXPERIAN,07/25/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,CONSUMER CREDIT REPORTING AGENCIES
28,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Gage,J,GENERAL PURCHASE,54.72,UFIRST  LAUNDRY SVCS,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,"MENS, WOMENS AND CHILDRENS UNIFORMS AND COMMERCIAL CLOTHING"
29,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Gann,D,CYLCARBONDIOXIDEIND200CGA3 MO|CYLCARBONDIOXIDEIND3,112.8,AIRGAS CENTRAL,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,CHEMICALS AND ALLIED PRODUCTS NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
30,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,George,D,GENERAL PURCHASE,42.8,UCR - SPARE PARTS WAREHOU,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,"COMPUTERS, COMPUTER PERIPHERAL EQUIPMENT, SOFTWARE"
31,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Gerlt,T,GENERAL PURCHASE,145.0,OK MEDICAL BOARD,07/27/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,GOVERNMENT SERVICES--NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
32,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Gerlt,T,GENERAL PURCHASE,33.49,TRAK1 TECHN,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,PROFESSIONAL SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
33,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Gerlt,T,GENERAL PURCHASE,3582.0,TELVENT,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,BUSINESS SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
34,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Gladden,V,GENERAL PURCHASE,154.69,UNITED REFRIG BR #75,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,"COMMERCIAL EQUIPMENT, NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED"
35,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,GODSEY,R,GENERAL PURCHASE,407.85,OPTIMUM ENERGY PROD,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
36,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Golay,B,GENERAL PURCHASE,28.75,OPERON BIOTECHNOLOGIES I,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
37,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Golay,B,MITSUBISHI K-91HG GL CS,94.64,FISHER SCI HUS,07/27/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
38,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Golliver,J,GENERAL PURCHASE,138.21,Business World Inc,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,"STATIONERY, OFFICE SUPPLIES, PRINTING AND WRITING PAPER"
39,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Gordon,D,Brother Printer MFC7860DW PCE,249.98,Amazon.com,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,BOOK STORES
40,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Gourley,A,GENERAL PURCHASE,25.65,NAPA AUTO PARTS,07/25/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,AUTOMOTIVE PARTS AND ACCESSORIES STORES
41,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Govindaraju,N,WRAP EA|WRAP EA|TIDY BUKET EA|FLEX CPLG EA|QWICK C,44.84,THE HOME DEPOT 3904,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,HOME SUPPLY WAREHOUSE STORES
42,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Graffman,M,ROOM CHARGES,862.8,COURTYARD BY MARRIOTT1103,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,COURTYARD BY MARRIOTT
43,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,O'Neill,P,GENERAL PURCHASE,183.62,WWW.GREENFARMTOYS.COM,07/29/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM,"HOBBY,TOY,AND GAME STORES"
44,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Constantine,G,GENERAL PURCHASE,157.5,I-CAR,07/25/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,SCHOOLS AND EDUCATIONAL SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
45,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Cowell,C,GENERAL PURCHASE,13.75,JAILHOUSE FEED  FARM,07/24/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,"PET SHOPS,PET FOOD AND SUPPLIES"
46,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,Cross,A,GENERAL PURCHASE,311.98,B&C BUSINESS PRODUCTS,07/24/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,BUSINESS SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
47,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,DALCOUR,K,GENERAL PURCHASE,1312.2,NATURAL WATER COMPANY LLC,07/24/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,BUSINESS SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
48,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,DALCOUR,K,GENERAL PURCHASE,118.72,NATURAL WATER COMPANY LLC,07/24/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,BUSINESS SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
49,201307,1000,OKLAHOMA STATE UNIVERSITY,DALCOUR,K,GENERAL PURCHASE,914.0,AUTO-CHLOR SERVICES INC,07/24/2013 12:00:00 AM,07/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,CATALOG MERCHANTS
442408,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,1305.4,MARMIC FIRE & SAFETY C,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,"COMMERCIAL EQUIPMENT, NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED"
442409,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,9590.0,FAIRPOINT COMMUNICATIONS,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,TELECOMMUNICATION SERVICES
442410,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Berry,C,ROOM CHARGES,188.0,EMBASSY SUITES NORMAN,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,EMBASSY SUITES
442411,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Berry,C,Depressed Ctr WhlT274.5 EA,129.5,WW GRAINGER,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,INDUSTRIAL SUPPLIES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442412,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Berry,C,ROOM CHARGES,251.3,SHERATON DENVER,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,SHERATON
442413,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cole,K,GENERAL PURCHASE,212.59,WALKER'S HARDWARE,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
442414,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cole,K,GENERAL PURCHASE,58.25,HAMILL EQUIPMENT INC.,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,MISCELLANEOUS REPAIR SHOPS AND RELATED SERVICES
442415,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Couch,J,GENERAL PURCHASE,339.99,ACME TOOLS #110,06/16/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
442416,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Couch,J,GENERAL PURCHASE,372.5,SCOVIL & SIDES HARDWARE C,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
442417,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Edmundson,M,GENERAL PURCHASE,11.04,QUANTIE SALES & SERVICE,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,"MISC. AUTOMOTIVE,AIRCRAFT,AND FARM EQUIPMENT DEALERS"
442418,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Gregory,J,GENERAL PURCHASE,77.0,LOCKE SUPPLY - WHC PRYOR,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
442419,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Howard,B,GBLC2-D1-15 EA|GBLC2-D1-03 EA|GBLC2-D1-02 EA|GBLC2,189.97,GRAYBAR ELECTRIC COMPANY,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,ELECTRICAL PARTS AND EQUIPMENT
442420,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Howard,B,Mushkin Enhanced Atlas Del PCE,1029.91,AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,BOOK STORES
442421,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Howard,B,GENERAL PURCHASE,337.99,OTHERWORLDC,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,ELECTRONICS STORES
442422,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Hunter,G,GENERAL PURCHASE,15.0,WWW.OKAPP.ORG,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,MEMBERSHIP ORGANIZATIONS--NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442423,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Hunter,G,GENERAL PURCHASE,31724.74,CHICKASAW TELECOM,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,TELECOMMUNICATION EQUIPMENT AND TELEPHONE SALES
442424,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Jaggars,J,GENERAL PURCHASE,33.27,WALKER'S HARDWARE,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
442425,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Jaggars,J,GENERAL PURCHASE,-1395.0,ESRI INC,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,COMPUTER SOFTWARE STORES
442426,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Johnson,K,LEXMARK C935 X940E X945E PCE,252.68,AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,BOOK STORES
442427,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,McGuire,D,GENERAL PURCHASE,411.58,ARROWHEAD YACHT CLUB,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,"MARINAS,MARINE SERVICE,AND SUPPLIES"
442428,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Nikolai,S,GENERAL PURCHASE,361.19,"TURNER DESIGNS, INC",06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,INDUSTRIAL SUPPLIES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442429,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Nikolai,S,1000PPM NITRTE-NTRGE EA,68.52,TFS FISHER SCI HUS,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
442430,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Nikolai,S,BAROMETER WITH CLOCK EA,33.01,TFS FISHER SCI HUS,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
442431,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Nikolai,S,HYDROCHLOR ACID TRAC EA|L-ASCORBIC ACID CRY EA|SOD,1250.78,TFS FISHER SCI HUS,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,DENTAL/LABORATORY/MEDICAL/OPHTHALMIC HOSP EQIP AND SUP.
442432,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Prince,S,ROOM CHARGES,194.79,THE FAIRMONT HOTEL DALLAS,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,FAIRMONT HOTELS CORP.
442433,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Ragsdale,M,MACL J1059 THIMBLE OPEN EA|MACL J1088 1-3/4 RND WA,575.0,STUART C IRBY,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,ELECTRICAL PARTS AND EQUIPMENT
442434,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Stroup,P,GENERAL PURCHASE,299.3,W.S. DARLEY & CO.,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,"DURABLE GOODS, NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED"
442435,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Stroup,P,1213188StainlessSteelFinis EA|3816x3YellowZincFini,295.72,FASTENAL COMPANY01,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
442436,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Stroup,P,GENERAL PURCHASE,339.76,PRAXAIR DISTRIBUTION I,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,WELDING SERVICES
442437,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Stroup,P,GENERAL PURCHASE,40.06,LOCKE SUPPLY - WHC PRYOR,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
442438,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Stroup,P,GENERAL PURCHASE,491.0,PRAXAIR DISTRIBUTION I,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,WELDING SERVICES
442439,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Stroup,P,1812PipeCapacity2853Height EA,319.98,FASTENAL COMPANY01,06/18/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE STORES
442440,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Stroup,P,Grease GunCordless18V1 EA,296.76,WW GRAINGER,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,INDUSTRIAL SUPPLIES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442441,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Wheeler,K,GENERAL PURCHASE,624.01,TOTAL RADIO INC,06/17/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,TELECOMMUNICATION EQUIPMENT AND TELEPHONE SALES
442442,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,136.0,MATHESON-308,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,CHEMICALS AND ALLIED PRODUCTS NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442443,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,25540.0,GENERATOR AND MOTOR SERVI,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,INDUSTRIAL SUPPLIES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442444,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,209.4,STANDLEY SYSTEMS LLC,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,"OFFICE, PHOTOGRAPHIC, PHOTOCOPY, AND MICROFILM EQUIPMENT"
442445,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,47561.0,TECHSICO ENTERPRISE,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,"ARCHITECTURAL,ENGINEERING,AND SURVEYING SERVICES"
442446,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,1018.0,T & L SUPPLY,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,INDUSTRIAL SUPPLIES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442447,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,898.59,MAILFINANCE,06/21/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,BUSINESS SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442448,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,2622.7,HAROLDS AUTO PARTS OF,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,AUTOMOTIVE PARTS AND ACCESSORIES STORES
442449,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,132790.14,EVANS ENTERPRISES,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,"COMMERCIAL EQUIPMENT, NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED"
442450,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,1307.58,YELLOWHOUSE MACHINERY CO-,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,"MISC. AUTOMOTIVE,AIRCRAFT,AND FARM EQUIPMENT DEALERS"
442451,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,Payment on Account Each,3302.6,O REILLY AUTO 00050559,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,AUTOMOTIVE PARTS AND ACCESSORIES STORES
442452,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,FUEL PUMP EA|FUEL PUMP GASKET EA|CLAMP 5 EA|COLLAR,189.13,WHITE STAR MACHINERY,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,"COMMERCIAL EQUIPMENT, NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED"
442453,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,992.0,TOTAL VALVE SYSTEMS,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,HARDWARE EQUIPMENT AND SUPPLIES
442454,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,2415.0,PRYOR WASTE & RECYCLING L,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,"UTILITIES - ELECTRIC,GAS,WATER,SANITARY"
442455,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,177.5,ACCURATE ENVIROMENTAL LAB,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,BUSINESS SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442456,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,32457.0,RED BUD SERVICE INC,06/19/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,PROFESSIONAL SERVICES NOT ELSEWHERE CLASSIFIED
442457,201406,98000,GRAND RIVER DAM AUTH.,Cardholder,e,GENERAL PURCHASE,4714.07,WARRENCAT CREDIT DEPT,06/20/2014 12:00:00 AM,06/23/2014 12:00:00 AM,MISCELLANEOUS AND SPECIALTY RETAIL STORES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- See inline notation for code explanation
- [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)
- [`pandas.Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)
- [`pandas.Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html)
- [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
- [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

  - [`Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# download the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/xapduodvxrzul6tjrupmlqiot4bpex')

# create the groups using groupby
categories = ['Cardholder Last Name', 'Cardholder First Initial']
groups = df.groupby(categories).size().reset_index(name='size')

# determine the quartile values to use with pd.cut
quartiles = groups['size'].quantile([.25, .5, .75]).tolist()

# add a lower and upper range for the bins in pd.cut
quartiles = [0] + quartiles + [float('inf')]

# add a quartiles column to groups, using pd.cut
groups['quartiles'] = pd.cut(groups['size'], bins=quartiles, labels=['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th'])

# merge df and groups
df = df.merge(groups, on=categories)

# groupby on categories and quartiles
dfg = df.groupby(categories + ['quartiles'])

# save the groups to individual csv files
for (fn, ln, q), g in dfg:

    # create the path
    path = Path(f'e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/Groups/{q}')

    # make the directory
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    
    # write the file without the size and quartiles columns
    g.iloc[:, :-2].to_csv(path / f'{fn}_{ln}.csv', index=False)
```